# Is there a way to find out when a sound has stopped playing in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, audio, browser

I'm creating a game. The levels are relatively short, and at the start of each one, the player hears a narration (a sound that lasts `x` seconds). It might happen that someone gets trough the level before the sound ends, and the new level will start playing its own sound over the previous one's sound. I want the sounds to queue, and for that, I need to know when a sound has stopped playing. Is there an event for that?

Comment: html5 games? Do you need support for older browsers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var mySound = new Audio('mySoundFile.ogg'); 
mySound.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    alert("Finished playing sound");
}, false);
mySound.play();
```

For other events, see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#mediaevents

Comment: Downvoted for w3schools link. If you could replace that with a more reliable source i'll gladly change it to an up vote.

Comment: I just found out two things I think is important to note. you can call a regular function  in there by doing   mySound.addEventListener('ended',myfunction,false);  but do NOT use mySound.addEventListener('ended',myfunction(),false); the first one works as expected, the 2nd one will call myfunction right as the sound starts playing not when it's done playing.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this link](http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html) useful. It has an example of playing multiple sounds that shows a way of tracking the whether the file is complete.

Basically, get the duration property of the audio and note when it starts playing. If the current time is later than the start time + duration, it's done.

Answer (score 0):

If your using the HTML5 `<audio>` element it fires an `ended` event when the end of an audio file is reached.

Answer (score -1):

You can play sound with SWF player (http://flash-mp3-player.net), it has callback function that will notify you once it finish.

The advantage of this approach is that it will work in HTML 4 browsers too.